# System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure when Calling WEBAPI in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have created one simple xamarin form application using PCL, which is showing data in listview using WEBAPI. When i call WebAPI , i am getting below error.

> ex = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while
> sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error:
> NameResolutionFailure   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse
> (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in
> <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d...

My WEBAPI:-

```
private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://servername/WEBAPI/api/employee/";
```

I am getting error on below code,

```
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);
```

If anybody faced same issue, Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

My RestClient Code:-

```
    public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
    {
        //var taskModels = new List<T>();
        var test = new List<T>();

        try
        {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

            var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

            test = taskModels;
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           
        }

        return test;
    }
```

Comment: is that the exact url of your web service? If so, it is not valid

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is incorrect. Please supply a fully qualified domain name

Edit: assuming you have some config that maps server ip address to the domain(host file, private dns, etc) just replace `msweb102`to whatever the ip address of your server is

*eg.* `127.0.0.1/WEBAPI/api/employee/`

Comment: i am getting below data , when i click my api.

Comment: <ArrayOfEmployee xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebAPI.Models">
<Employee>
<Department>IT&A</Department>
<EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
<EmployeeName>Subanesh</EmployeeName>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Department>IT&A</Department>
<EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
<EmployeeName>RAvi</EmployeeName>
</Employee>
</ArrayOfEmployee>

Comment: ping `http://msweb102/` on your pc to get the ip address, Then replace `http://msweb102/` to that IP Address

Comment: Please help me on above issues

Comment: is it the same when you paste in on a browser? If you are still able to see the data you previously pasted. Then make sure that your phone and your pc is connected on the same network, and they can ping each other

Comment: After Changing WEBAPI to IP address , i couldnt see data in my pc browser also.

Comment: is your api currently just being debugged/ran on compiler/IDE (Visual Studio, etc)? If so, please deploy it to your [IIS](http://www.betterhostreview.com/turn-on-iis-windows-10.html) (assuming you're running windows)

Comment: After changing msweb102 to ip address i m getting error like -404 File or Directory not found

Comment: Try to resolve your settings on IIS, because `192.168.33.91/WEBAPI/api/employee` should work on pc browser if it was configured properly. Also double check if your emulator is running a **bridged connection** to your pc's network, and not on its own network

Comment: Please could you help me , how to do bridged connection in my PC and emulator. i am trying to connect internet in my android emulator for the past 2 days but couldnot. please help me to connect internet on emulator. i am using - Android Emulator - AVD_for_Nexus_One_by_Google and API 23

Answer (score 0):

Where do you got error on simulator on on real device.

In this case, it looks like that your test environment can not access the API environment

Change MSWeb02 to become IP address and make sure you are setup window firewall to allow outbound connection on port 80.

The easy way to test it work is open web api in the browser of the device. If that work, your code will work.

Comment: i am working on emulator. i have hosted my webapi to my local server. i will try to open webapi in emulator. Thank u

Comment: if i run in emulator , should emulator have connected to internet ?